# Download multiple xml files into a single file without parsing

Tags: python, xml

I have to download multiple xml files with unique urls without parsing into a single file for keyword analysis.

I used the following python script which is getting executed but the output file does not contain any text. Where am I going wrong?

```
import requests

# List of URLs of the XML pages you want to scrape
xml_urls = [
    "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/xbrl/CG_92090_946801_11102023020327_WEB.xml",
    "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/xbrl/CG_92138_947508_11102023050314_WEB.xml",
    # Add more URLs as needed
]

# Output file where the content will be saved
output_file = "output.txt"

# Function to scrape XML content from a URL and save it to the output file
def scrape_and_save_xml(url, output_file):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Write the raw content to the output file
            with open(output_file, "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                file.write(response.text + "\n")
            print(f"Scraped {url}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch {url} (Status Code: {response.status_code})")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error while scraping {url}: {str(e)}")

# Clear the contents of the output file (if it already exists)
with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.truncate()

# Loop through the XML URLs and scrape their content
for xml_url in xml_urls:
    scrape_and_save_xml(xml_url, output_file)

print("Scraping completed. The content has been saved to", output_file)
```

Comment: What should the expected output be? Concatenating two valid XML files creates a file which os no longer valid XML.

Comment: @tripleee I guess it doesn't matter if it's still valid xml or not in first place. He just wants that output.txt filled with the content of both xml urls. After that the next problem will become the invalid xml

Comment: The remote server simply seems to refuse connections from `requests`. It just hangs, and if you press ctrl-C the traceback reveals that it's was trying to create an SSL connection. With Chrome I can connect without issue.

Comment: The symptoms should be included in your question, not left for us to discover. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Please ensure that you have access to write content into the output.txt. e. g. before checking if the file exists.

Comment: A Well Formed XML file has only one root tag.  If you are merging well formed XML you have to remove the ending tag on first file and remove first tag on second file.  A lot of log xml log files are not well formed and have multiple tags at root.  You error is probably due to library giving error that you have more than one tag at the root.

Comment: @tripleee : The OP created an xml file with more than one tag at root.  It is valid, just not Well Formed.  The XML specification allows for multiple tags at root, but a lot of libraries will give errors when not well formed.  Usually the libraries have options to handle xml files that are not well formed.

Comment: @jdweng how can be valid if it's not well formed?

Comment: @LMC : Read the Xml Specification.  Well formed means only one tag at root.  The xml specification allows for arrays to be a root of xml which is NOT Well Formed.

Comment: @jdweng well-formed is a [requisite for validity](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-documents). Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/2834978)

Comment: @LMC : You are absolutely wrong and the link you provided agree with me.  XML Specification specifically allows appending which creates an array at the root.  Many applications use XML for log files.  To open and remove end tag when appending is time consuming and has no benefits.

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand what you mean. You need a custom parser to parse `<root></root><root></root>` since it's an string that MIGHT be converted to XML but it's not XML in itself. Also, which part of the links I provided  'agrees with you'.

Comment: @LMC : Valid XML only has one root tag".  The amount of time and resources it takes to amend to XML is large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending from existing answer, here's how to build a single well formed XML from current responses as is. If response format changes then regex should be used instead of split()

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

xml_urls = [
    "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/xbrl/CG_92090_946801_11102023020327_WEB.xml",
    "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/xbrl/CG_92138_947508_11102023050314_WEB.xml",
]

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0"
}

xmldecl = ''
response = ''
with open("out.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for url in xml_urls:
        # make a single split, i.e. at the first \n only
        body = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text.split('\n', 1)
        xmldecl = body[0]
        response += body[1]
    print(f"{xmldecl}\n<root>\n{response}</root>", file=f_out)

# should not rise any exception
t = etree.parse('out.txt')
print(t.getroot().tag)
```

Result

```
root
```

If XML documents are not formatted `split()` will not work. Assuming the xml declaration is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` (38 characters length)

```
    body = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    xmldecl = body[:38]
    response += body[38:]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get correct response from the server set `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```py
import requests

xml_urls = [
    "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/xbrl/CG_92090_946801_11102023020327_WEB.xml",
    "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/corporate/xbrl/CG_92138_947508_11102023050314_WEB.xml",
]

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0"
}

with open("out.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for url in xml_urls:
        print(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, file=f_out)
```

This creates `out.txt` with the two XMLs concatenated.